# Co-locate flutter test files to source

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Putting test files in the `test` directory involves mental gymnastics of remembering to move test file when sources move or to even find a corresponding test file.

Is there a way in flutter to place test files next the source?

`flutter test -h` doesn't have any path related options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with

```
flutter test lib/**/*_test.dart
```

Found the hint from Dart test package readme at https://github.com/dart-lang/test/tree/master/pkgs/test#running-tests